# Initialize React class/component on existing Website with attributes

Tags: reactjs

I want to build an component to a website using React (build with webpack). I don't want to make an complicated 'installation' to the existing site. Just add the script and it 'works'.

I can't figure out how to create a component/class and add it with parameters.
This code will initialize the component on the page but ignore messageText and initialCount. I've also tried without 'data-'

index.html

```
<div id="Docker" data-messageText="Test user" data-initialCount="2"/>
<script src="assets/js/docker.js"></script>
```

docker.jsx

```
var React = require('react');

var Docker = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            count: parseInt(this.props.initialCount),
            label: this.props.messageText
        };
    },

    handleClick: function () {
        this.setState({count: parseInt(this.state.count) + 1});
    },

    render: function() {

        return (
            <div>
            <div>Hello from: {this.state.label}</div>
            <div onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.count}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }

});

React.render(
  <Docker />,
  document.getElementById('Docker')
);
```

A wish is to add the component in any webpage with:

```
<Docker messageText="Test user" initialCount="2"/>
<script src="assets/js/docker.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the values from the div and pass them to your Docker component, like this

```
var Docker = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            count: parseInt(this.props.initialCount),
            label: this.props.messageText
        };
    },

    handleClick: function () {
        this.setState({count: parseInt(this.state.count) + 1});
    },

    render: function() {
        return  (
            <div data-messageBox={this.state.label} data-initialCount={this.state.count}>
            <div>Hello from: {this.state.label}</div>
            <div onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.count}</div>
            </div>
            );
    }

});

var docker = document.getElementById('Docker');
var messageText = docker.dataset.messagetext;
var initialCount = docker.dataset.initialcount;
ReactDOM.render(
  <Docker messageText={messageText} initialCount={initialCount}/>,
  document.getElementById('Docker')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/40824/